# Quickly trying different colours in the GIMP

Tags: gimp

Currently I've got the "Change foreground colour" dialog open and whenever I change the colour I need to click inside the selection to activate the Bucket Fill. Is there a better way? ;)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut for the 'Fill with foreground color'. Try that instead of the bucket fill.

Comment: Thanks, that's better, but ideally I'd like to play with the colour picker and have the image updated immediately.

Comment: Right, try Colors -> Colorize and play with the sliders. Is that more like it? Choosing a specific hex color will be harder though.

Comment: yeah, that's good too but the dialog isn't as nice